# MBP 16 Graphics Performance External Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, performance, gpu

My MacBook Pro GPU Benchmark score/ render times & game performance very quickly get slashed almost by a factor of 2 when I connect an external monitor. I'm seeing the same behaviour on MacOS as well as Windows. Performance returns to normal almost immediately after switching the the built-in screen.

Do you guys have any ideas what might be causing this/ what steps can be taken to mitigate this issue?

I tried connecting the monitor using:

- Display Port <-> CalDigit dock <-> MacBook
- Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI Cable <-> MacBook
- HDMI <-> USB-A/C/HDMI Dongle <-> MacBook

The (perhaps relevant) hardware specs of this particular unit are:

- 32 GB Ram
- Core i7 6-core base
- Radeon Pro 5500M 8GB

Comment: What makes you think it's not completely normal? I'd call this expected behaviour, double the screen area, double the workload.

Comment: The built-in display is deactivated when the lid is shut and the external monitor I'm using has a resolution of 2560 x 1440 and so my expectation is anything resolution-dependent should actually start performing better with an external display.

Comment: Benchmark scores are artificial, so what you are seeing could be a meaningless artifact of how the benchmark is computed or reported. What are you using to compute the benchmark? How is the result defined? What is the native resolution of the external monitor and what resolution did you set it to? If you picked a resolution that is not native to the monitor ("larger text" or "more space") or if the display has PPI in the area of 150, the Mac will render the image to a virtual monitor and then bitmap that image to your monitor's native size, which could account for the performance decrease.